# Как сделать, чтобы приложение не запускалось второй раз?

Tags: delphi

Предположим, я нажал на ярлык программы, программа запустилась, через некоторое время спряталось с помощью Hide, второй раз нажимаю на ярлык и она при этом разворачивается и становится видимой на переднем плане, если запущено много окон?

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь [мьютексами](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81)(mutex). Можете рассматривать это как глобальную переменную на уровне операционной системы.

Выберите какое-то имя, например `"MyAppMutex"`. При запуске приложения создавайте мьютекс c этим именем. Если мьютекс создан успешно - продолжаем работать, если нет - завершайте работу приложения.

См. [CreateMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

**UPD0**

```
program Project1;
uses
  Forms, Windows, Messages,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}
var
  Mutex : THandle;
begin
  Mutex := CreateMutex(nil, True, 'My_Unique_Application_Mutex_Name');
  if (Mutex <> 0) and (GetLastError <> ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) then
  begin
    Application.Initialize;
    Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
    Application.Run;
    if Mutex <> 0 then begin
      CloseHandle(Mutex);
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Извините, не понял! Объясните, пожалуйста!!!

Answer (score 0):

В файле проекта:

```
var xHand: THandle;

begin
 xHand:=CreateMutex(nil,false,'206f731a-73a3-4b07-bb35-1f858cb8fb67');
 If (GetLastError = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) then
 MessageDlg(' Уже запущено! ',mtInformation, [mbOk], 0);
 Application.Initialize;
 Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
 Application.Run;
 ReleaseMutex(xHand);
end.
```